# Display the count of array in ng-repeat using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a JSON response which contains an array of data.

```
 $scope.Load = function () {
        $http.post(elasticSearchURL, { "aggs": { "By_type": { "terms": { "field": "Name" }, "aggs": { "By_color": { "terms": { "field": "Color" } } } } } }).
          then(function (response) {
              $scope.modelList = response;


          }, function (response) {
          });

    }
```

I would like to display the count of each element in the JSON.

**MyHtml Code**

```
<div ng-repeat="fruits in modelList.data.hits.hits | unique : '_source.fruitsName' | orderBy:'_source.fruitsName'   ">

{fruits._source.name.length}

</div>
```

My Json data will be like this

```
{"_id":"e-AB2","_version":1,"found":true, "_source":{"name":"Apple", "color":"red"}}},
{"_id":"e-AB2","_version":1,"found":true, "_source":{"name":"Apple", "color":"red"}}},
{"_id":"e-AB2","_version":1,"found":true, "_source":{"name":"Apple", "color":"red"}}}
```

It displays only the length of the fruitname "Apple" length:5. I want to display the array length of _source.name

I have tried `{{$index.length}}` but it showing the count as 1 since I am using `"unique:"` in the `<div>`

How it can be achieved in angularjs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what's the json you get back in response like, can you post pls

Comment: Without seeing data structure we have no idea what to look for. Using `$index.length` makes no sense

Comment: if i understand what are you trying to display then you should display _source length not name length

Comment: Now that data is added to question,what exactly are you wanting from that data. There is no array within `_source`. A proper question would provide expected results which you haven't done

Comment: it's really not clear exactly what you are trying to accomplish here; the JSON you posted doesn't really make sense in relation to the `ng-repeat` you posted.

Comment: @charlietfl I want to get the count of "Apple" inside the ng-repeat. Liek that I have "orange" , "pineapple", etc. I want to display the count of fruit name.

Comment: are you just trying to get the count of the number of items the filter returned?

Comment: As I see you apply unique filter and data you want is discarded. You need to use another filter, or create one.

Comment: map that in controller or service then. WHole question is still unclear

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that I understand what your goal is here, but I'm going to make an attempt.

Comment: `<span class="card">{{fruits._source.name}} <b>{{fruits._source.color}}</b></span>`. Like that I am looking to display the count of the corresponding fruits also

Comment: actually looking at this again, what you are trying to do isn't sensible with the way your data is structured.

Comment: what you are trying to do is count the number of occurrences of an object property within an array, but you can't use `ng-repeat` to help you with that, because you are filtering out the duplicate  occurrences before they can be counted.  You will need to create a separate function to compile an array of each value and it's corresponding count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest approach is create  hashmap that contains the counts:

```
$scope.counts = {};

$http.post(elasticSearchURL, postData).then(function (response) {
    $scope.modelList = response.data;
    response.data.forEach(function (item) {
        var source = item._source.name;
        if (!$scope.counts.hasOwnProperty(source)) {
            $scope.counts[source] = 0;
        }
        $scope.counts[source]++;
    });
});
```

Then in the view you can use:

```
Count = {{counts[fruits._source.name]}}
```

`$scope.counts` will look like:

```
{ 'Apple':3, 'Orange':5}
```

What you probably want to do is map all the data to a different array in this same fashion and get rid of the `unique` filter since there is no way to do what you are asking directly in the view

Comment: what you have described is the exact thing I am looking for. I tried your approach, but in `$scope.count' is empty nothing was added into it.

Comment: create a plunker demo that replicates problem

Comment: What is that `postData` you added in `$http.post(elasticSearchURL, postData)'

Comment: was simply to abbreviate the `aggs` object you showed in question

Comment: In dotnet I don't have any postData option . I have postMessage option only. Shall I use Postmessage instead of postData

Comment: no, that is simply a variable I created to represent the data you are posting

Comment: Its not working dude. I couldn't create the plunker code. Something is missing

Comment: switch to `response.data` ...`then()` returns whole promise object .... works here  http://plnkr.co/edit/hVWYhs6CuuDbafqTTnui?p=preview

Comment: I think I got wrong json response. This is my exact json what I am getting as response. `{"took":11,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":4784,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_score":1.0,"_source":{"name":"Apple","Color":"Red"}},{"_score":1.0,"_source":{"name":"Apple","Color":"Red"}}]}}'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89836/discussion-between-mangoski-and-charlietfl).